# Decorate class methods dynamically raises error in python

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23224383/how-to-decorate-all-methods-in-a-class-can-i-just-decorate-the-class) in order to decorate all methods of a class. This is my version of the code:

```
def decorate_object_methods(object_to_decorate, decorator):
    for name in dir(object_to_decorate):
        attr = getattr(object_to_decorate, name)
        if callable(attr):
            wrapped = decorator(attr)
            setattr(object_to_decorate, name, wrapped)
```

The problem is that I am getting this exception in the last sentence of the method:

```
TypeError: __class__ must be set to a class, not 'function' object
```

I can't find what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Class is also a callable object. You have not excluded this special case.